# SQLAlchemy - check if query found any results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I check if a query found any results?

```
result = db.engine.execute(sql, id=foo)
// check if result has rows ...
for row in result:
  ...
```

Tried this:

```
if result is None:
    print("reuslt is None!")
```

and checked length:

```
print("result len", len(result))
```

Comment: It also depends on what results are getting returned. The length can be useful if you are sure that either it will return some rows or nothing but cannot be used if the result itself is returning a tuple with `None` object in it. In the latter case, the length would be one which has a single tuple containing none object. Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 21):

`all()` may be quite slow for some databases, `count()` is better but `first()` is even faster for large databases and complex queries. For example:

```
x = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.read==True).first() is not None
```

Comment: This is still overselecting. What if `Post` contains a property for "full text" and what if this post it found is all of war and peace?

Comment: You are right. In retrospect, it is probably better to do it like this.


x = db.session.query(Post.read).filter(Post.read==True).first() is not None


I don't have a project to test it right now, so I won't change the original answer.

Answer (score 7):

**rowcount** works for me, as a simple way of checking if a query is empty in SQLAlchemy.

```
  results = db.engine.execute(tbl.select(<YOUR-SELECT-QUERY>))
  num_results = results.rowcount
  if int(num_results) == 0:
      print('NO RESULTS FOUND')
  else:
      print(str(num_results)+' RESULTS FOUND')
```

Answer (score 3):

**len** is the better way. You were near:

```
print("result len", len(result.all()))
```

You cant access to a BaseQuery len if you dont get all of its elements.

Compare **result** with **None** is ok if you want to know if its empty.

Comment: correct me if im wrong but this would fetch all records. pretty expensive operation if you're just trying to see if "any" are returned

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a way to do this.

Here is the code:

```
blogs = Post.query.filter_by(subcategory_id=subcategory, category_id=2)

    if blogs.count() == 0 :
        return redirect(url_for('blogs.travel', subcategory=subcategory))
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I used the code below and worked well. If the query.first() tuple returns a result different from 0 it means there's something in that query.

```
sql = f"SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users_table WHERE user_name = '{user_name}'"
query = engine.execute(sql)
if query.first()[0] != 0:
    do_something
```

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me:

```
flag=0
present=True

for i in result:
    flag=1
    break

if(flag==0)
    present=False #No result found
```